# OnPaint: Two or more overlapping Images in Visual Studio 2017 C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, png, overlapping

I saw an interesting thread about overlapping PNG images using OnPaint.  But after trying out the code in Visual Studio 2017, it doesn't work.

Here is the code:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    System.Drawing.Graphics e.Graphics();
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    System.Drawing.Point point = new Point(x, y);
    obj.Clear(Color.White);
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("hex.png"), point);
    e.Graphics.Dispose();
}
```

Code to display overlapping images:

```
e.Graphics.DrawImage(Image.FromFile("hex.png"), point);
e.Graphics.DrawImage(Image.FromFile("hex.png"), point);
```

I placed both code snippets in the Form's code.  Nothing happened.  Should they both belong in a form and/or class, and if this code doesn't work, what code should I use for Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: `System.Drawing.Graphics e.Graphics();` ???  `obj.Clear(Color.White);` what is obj?? `e.Graphics.Dispose();` you didn't create it, you must not dispose of it. What does _code doesn't work_ mean?? _Code to display overlapping images:_ it draws the same image at the same spot twice. Why? Also: look into `Graphics.CompositingMode`

Comment: _I placed both code snippets in the Form's code. Nothing happened._ Doubtful. The 1st thing to happen would be two compiler errors. Or one if you had cached a Graphics object obj. NEVER do that!! (You have a nice e.Graphics to use.) And then the image would show or an error that it was not found. Please: Post only real code!